# How to increase code coverage in test class for apex page message

Tags: unit-test

How do I increase code coverage on the ApexPages (noted after the catch exception)?

```
public pagereference savesamp()
{
 try{
       upsert samObj;
    }Catch(Exception ex)

   {
     ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage());
     ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
     return null;
    }
 return new pagereference('/'+samObj.id);
}
```

Comment: You will need to cause the upset to fail for some reason. Could be by providing a duplicate value for a unique field or not populating required values. If you cannot cause an error to be thrown then you need to make a decision: artificially enter the catch block by causing a deliberate error during a specific test or just leave it uncovered and question if the catch is necessary (if you cannot cause it to fail then will it ever?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this -

```
Test.StartTest();
Test.setCurrentPage(Page.yourpage);//replace with our page name    
List<Apexpages.Message> msgs = ApexPages.getMessages();
        boolean b = false;
        for(Apexpages.Message msg:msgs){
            if (msg.getDetail().contains('A user account for this email address already exists') b = true;
        }
        system.assert(b);
Test.stopTest();
```

Basically "ApexPages.getMessages()" can give you all page messages

Comment: How does that throw an exception that is caught thus displaying the page message?

Comment: Create or update samobj with mandatory fields not populated. It will throw an exception. And then run this page message code

Comment: That worked but it unfortunately didn't raise the code coverage.

Comment: Which lines not getting covered?